# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (128, 75, 1) but got array with shape (1, 128, 1)

Tags: python

I am loading melspectogram to a cnn. These is the code of the model and the shape of the data. But am still getting these error

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                        input_shape=(128, 75, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

shape of the data

```
print(train_set_m.shape)
print(train_classes_m_hot.shape)
print(test_set_m.shape)
print(test_classes_m_hot.shape)
```

(75, 1, 128, 1)
(75, 1, 10, 1)
(25, 1, 128, 1)
(25, 1, 10, 1)

```
These is the code I am fiting my model
# Deep Learning Parameters
batch_size = 5 # Number of samples per gradient update.
epochs = 200    # An epoch is an iteration over the entire x and y data provided.

# Train Model
hist = model.fit(train_set_m, train_classes_m_hot, verbose=1, 
                    batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(test_set_m,test_classes_m_hot))
```

I have 10 classes I want to predict

These is the error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (128, 75, 1) but got array with shape (1, 128, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 128, 1)))

Anyway, your data seems to be rather 1D: you only have one significant dimension, with size 128, the others are dummy (size 1). So a better idea would be to reformat your data in true 1D and then use 1D convolutions.

Comment: These is the error   ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_9/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,128,1], [3,3,1,32].

Comment: Even Wnen I try ID ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_8_input to have shape (75, 128) but got array with shape (1, 128)